# Нужен скрипт регуляции громкости видео и паузы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input для регуляции скорости восспроизвидения видео

```
<input type="range" class="form-range range" value="1" min="0.01" max="5" step="0.01" id="snipsnapp_speed_control">

  // Контроль скорости
  document.querySelector('#snipsnapp_speed_control').addEventListener('input', function(){
    if(document.querySelector('video') !== null){
      document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = this.value;
    }
  })
```

Проблема в том, что когда фокус наведен на этот input, а не на видео, то нельзя регулировать громкость видео клавишами вверх и вниз, а также нельзя пробелом ставить на паузу и снимать с паузы.

Я скрипты писать не умею, только адаптировать те которые нахожу в сети. Пробовал прицепить к событию нажатия кнопки (то что снизу) разные скрипты, но ничего не сработало.

```
else if (event.code === "ArrowDown") {
    ...
}
```

Может Вы подскажете простое решение на js или jquery, что вставить туда где три точки, чтобы убавлять/повышать громкость на 10% от абсолютной, ну и с паузой/воспроизведением?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#snipsnapp_speed_control').addEventListener('focus', () => { document.querySelector('video').focus() })`, при фокусе на `input`, фокус будет переводиться на видео :) (ВНИМАНИЕ, КОСТЫЛЬ)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ааа нет, так не пойдет. Вы сломали мне все остальные сочетания клавиш :))

Comment: @ΝNL993 туда бы добавить скрипт типа если нажате клавиши "стрелка вниз", то убавить громкость на 10% от абсолютной (не от той что сейчас, а от максимальной), и так же с паузой/воспроизведением

Comment: если серьёзно, то просто повесьте слушатели на `window`, тоесть: `window.addEventListener('keydown', ...)`, а там уже проверяйте по клавише что вам надо делать, советую вам [`switch case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), работает примерно так: `switch ('hello') { case 'hello': break; default: break; }`

Comment: @ΝNL993 я использую конструкцию типа else if (event.code === "ArrowDown") { ... } . Вот у меня вся проблема там где три точки, я тупо не знаю как регулировать громкость и паузу.

Comment: Погодите, вы хотите чтобы пользователь мог регулировать только 10% из 100% в громкости или что? А паузу вроде бы легко сделать, просто смотрите являться ли `event.code` - `Space`, если так, тогда выполняете текущий код: `yourVideoElement[yourVideoElement.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']()` (Код от *Опан*), то есть код будет останавливать или воспроизводить видео в зависимости от того на паузе оно или нет.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Про громкость: тупа нажал стрелку вниз - громкость уменшитись из 100% до 90%, еще раз нажал - уменшитись до 80% и так далее. Для увеличения громкости обратный процесс.

Comment: Короче, уж лучше опубликую как ответ, а вы дальше с кодом разберётесь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам решение:

```js
var videoElement = document.querySelector('video')
var currentVolume = 100

videoElement.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
})

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch (e.code) {
    case 'Space':
      videoElement[videoElement.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']()
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      currentVolume -= 10
      setVolume()
      break
    case 'ArrowUp':
      currentVolume += 10
      setVolume()
      break
  }
})

function setVolume() {
  currentVolume = currentVolume > 100
    ? 100
  : currentVolume < 0
    ? 0
  : currentVolume

  videoElement.volume = currentVolume * 1 / 100
}
```

```html
<video src="https://audio-video.gnu.org/video/short--undated--rms--free-software-four-freedoms.ogv" controls=""></video>

<input type="range" value="50" max="100" min="0">
```

### Объяснение:

Сначала объявляем переменные с самим элементом и текущим уровнем громкости, далее убираем все стандартные события нажатия клавиш методом `preventDefault`, далее проверяем какая клавиша была нажата, если пробел, делаем проверку, ставить на паузу видео или нет, если стрелка вниз, тогда опускаем громкость на 10%, если вверх поднимаем.

##### Функция `setVolume`:

Если громкость более 100%, ставим её на 100, если меньше 0 тогда ставим 0, после, по такой формуле `N * 1 / 100` (Пример: `85 * 1 / 100 === 0.85`) получаем громкость для видео в нужном нам формате.

Comment: Ха! Оно работает! Ура!
Спасибо

Comment: @Юра не за что :) Если возникнут вопросы по коду, пишите.